# How can I effectively pull out human readable strings/terms from code automatically?

Tags: python, line, cpu-word

I'm trying to determine the most common words, or "terms" (I think) as I iterate over many different files.

Example - For this line of code found in a file:

```
for w in sorted(strings, key=strings.get, reverse=True):
```

I'd want these unique strings/terms returned to my dictionary as keys:

```
for
w
in
sorted
strings
key
strings
get
reverse
True
```

However, I want this code to be tunable so that I can return strings with periods or other characters between them as well, because I just don't know what makes sense yet until I run the script and count up the "terms" a few times:

```
strings.get
```

How can I approach this problem? It would help to understand how I can do this one line at a time so I can loop it as I read my file's lines in. I've got the basic logic down but I'm currently just doing the tallying by unique line instead of "term":

```
strings = dict()
fname = '/tmp/bigfile.txt'

with open(fname, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line in strings:
            strings[line] += 1
        else:
            strings[line] = 1

for w in sorted(strings, key=strings.get, reverse=True):
    print str(w).rstrip() + " : " + str(strings[w])
```

(Yes I used code from my little snippet here as the example at the top.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only python token you want to keep together is the `object.attr` construct then all the tokens you are interested would fit into the regular expression

```
\w+\.?\w*
```

Which basically means "one or more alphanumeric characters (including `_`) optionally followed by a `.` and then some more characters"

note that this would also match number literals like `42` or  `7.6` but that would be easy enough to filter out afterwards.

then you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the actual counting for you:

```
import collections
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\w+\.?\w*")

#here I'm using the source file for `collections` as the test example
with open(collections.__file__, "r") as f:
    tokens = collections.Counter(t.group() for t in pattern.finditer(f.read()))
    for token, count in tokens.most_common(5): #show only the top 5
        print(token, count)
```

Running python version 3.6.0a1 the output is this:

```
self 226
def 173
return 170
self.data 129
if 102
```

which makes sense for the `collections` module since it is full of classes that use `self` and define methods, it also shows that it does capture `self.data` which fits the construct you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you. Now what if I wanted something like `hello$world` (the $ ... some of the files aren't actual code btw) to match as a complete term as well (instead of `hello` and `underscore`)? I'm going to have to tune this a lot. Will I just need to start making a bunch of regex "rules"?

Comment: giving specific examples of patterns is fairly easy, generalizing a pattern to fit several can be difficult, especially if you are not very familiar with `re`.  I know I usually end up getting the basic pattern with re then use `str` methods to remove exceptions.